# Linking boost_1_55_0 asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I'm using this in my makefile to build my program:

```
all:    server.cpp
g++ -o server server.cpp -I ~/boost/include -L~/boost/lib -Wl,-rpath,~/boost/lib -lboost_system -lboost_thread -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1
```

When I compile I get these warnings:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.53.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so, may conflict with libboost_system.so.5
```

When I run my program I receive the warning :

```
 ./server: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.53.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

the -Wl/rpath command is not working for me at the moment. I have also tired using

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/boost/lib
```

before I run my program and I get this back from the terminal:

```
export: relocation error: export: symbol errno, version GLIBC_2.0 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

What can I do to specify what library I want to use when I execute the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries are (usually) `boost/lib/stage/lib`, not `boost/lib`.

Also the dynamic loader **does not support `~` expansion**. Use the fully qualified path, e.g.

```
 -Wl,-rpath,/home/hededo/boost/stage/lib
```

Or, indeed, as I showed in my previous answer

```
 -Wl,-rpath,"$HOME/boost/stage/lib"
```

The quotes are just to make it work if `$HOME` contains special characters (like whitespace)

You can also look at

- [static linking](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/tutorial/linkage.html) - so  you can use Boost but never rely on any external shared library for it
- the BCP utility is a tool for extracting subsets of Boost (here: [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html))

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the [non-boost asio](http://think-async.com/Asio/AsioAndBoostAsio) which doesn't require linking with boost.

Comment: Interesting argument. I am looking into this now. Thank you

Comment: I think most libraries can be - optionally - configured for header-only with Boost proper. Then, there are **[static linking](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/tutorial/linkage.html)** and [the BCP utility is a tool for extracting subsets of Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html). Both of which are _more_ generically applicable IMO.

Comment: I don't think asio has that option; it depends on boost system (and optionally boost thread) for error code. You could always include that cpp in your project. BCP is not very reliable. In my experience you end up having to patch part of what BCP produces.