# boost gather a boost vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector, mpi

I have a distributed boost::numeric::ublas::vector distributed_boost_vector and i would like to gather in the root processor the whole distributed boost vector.
I am trying to use the function:

```
template<typename T> 
void gather(const communicator & comm, const T & in_value, T * out_values, 
          int root);
```

writing

```
boost::mpi::gather<boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> >
  (boost_comm, distributed_boost_vector, all_boost_vector, 0);
```

where all_boost_vector is a boost::numeric::ublas::vector

I receive "no matching function for call" error in compilation, why?

Comment: No reason to specify the template argument explicitly. It'll get deduced

Answer (score 1):

The most relevant overloads are:

```
void gather( const boost::mpi::communicator &comm, const T &in_value, T *out_values, int root )
void gather( const boost::mpi::communicator &comm, const T &in_value, int root )
void gather( const boost::mpi::communicator &comm, const T &in_value, std::vector<T> &out_values, int root )
```

So either pass by pointer:

```
boost::mpi::gather(boost_comm, distributed_boost_vector, &all_boost_vector, 0);
```

Or pass std::vector for `out_values`:

```
std::vector<ublasv> out_values;
boost::mpi::gather(boost_comm, distributed_boost_vector, out_values, 0);
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ade031e9d82bbd5f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/collectives/gather.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::mpi::communicator boost_comm;
    typedef boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> ublasv;

    ublasv distributed_boost_vector, all_boost_vector;
    boost::mpi::gather(boost_comm, distributed_boost_vector, &all_boost_vector, 0);

    std::vector<ublasv> out_values;
    boost::mpi::gather(boost_comm, distributed_boost_vector, out_values, 0);
}
```

Comment: The compiler now gives: main.o: In function `__tcf_10':
main.cpp:(.text+0xfd9): undefined reference to `boost::serialization::extended_type_info::key_unregister() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0xfe3): undefined reference to `boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::type_unregister()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xffb): undefined reference to `boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::~extended_type_info_typeid_0()'
main.o: In function `__tcf_5':....and so on. It seems that it does not recognize the  ublasv as a serializable vector

Comment: @AntonellaLongo that's a linker error. It did link with me. Did you link to the necessary libraries? Add `-pthread -lboost_system -lboost_serialization` and possibly more (mpi, boost_thread etc)

Comment: I have the boost installed not in /usr/lib, but is /home/boost (i do not have root access), so how can i add those libraries? I also use an automake system to configure and make my library, where should i add the names of the other libraries that you suggest?

Comment: @AntonellaLongo I'm not an expert in autotools. You should ask your project lead - or the one who set that up. Regarding linking to a custom version see **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22313790/85371)** or **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22905480/85371)** e.g. You can always ask another question about your build tool setup, perhaps.